# NLog Exception on Log to File (Unity project)

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'm using programmatic configuration with NLog and am encountering the following error whenever the log file should be written to:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRule..ctor
>   (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference identity, Int32
>   accessMask, Boolean isInherited, InheritanceFlags inheritanceFlags,
>   PropagationFlags propagationFlags) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.AccessControl/AuthorizationRule.cs:61)
>   System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule..ctor
>   (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference identity, Int32
>   accessMask, Boolean isInherited, InheritanceFlags inheritanceFlags,
>   PropagationFlags propagationFlags, AccessControlType type)
>   System.Security.AccessControl.MutexAccessRule..ctor
>   (System.Security.Principal.IdentityReference identity, MutexRights
>   eventRights, AccessControlType type)
>   NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender.CreateSharableMutex
>   (System.String mutexNamePrefix)
>   NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender.CreateSharableArchiveMutex
>   ()
>   NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.RetryingMultiProcessFileAppender.CreateArchiveMutex
>   () NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.BaseFileAppender..ctor (System.String
>   fileName, ICreateFileParameters createParameters)
>   NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.RetryingMultiProcessFileAppender..ctor
>   (System.String fileName, ICreateFileParameters parameters)
>   NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.RetryingMultiProcessFileAppender+Factory.NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.IFileAppenderFactory.Open
>   (System.String fileName, ICreateFileParameters parameters)
>   NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.FileAppenderCache.AllocateAppender
>   (System.String fileName) NLog.Targets.FileTarget.WriteToFile
>   (System.String fileName, NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.Byte[]
>   bytes, Boolean justData) NLog.Targets.FileTarget.ProcessLogEvent
>   (NLog.LogEventInfo logEvent, System.String fileName, System.Byte[]
>   bytesToWrite) NLog.Targets.FileTarget.Write (NLog.LogEventInfo
>   logEvent) NLog.Targets.Target.Write (AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)

Google doesn't know anything about this error, as far as I can see.  The following is my configuration code:

```
public static void SetupLogging()
    {
        // Can unity debug be redirected to go through Nlog?
        var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
        var consoleTarget = new ConsoleTarget("console");
        config.AddTarget("console", consoleTarget);

        //var logsPath = UtilsIO.GetResourcesPath(UtilsIO.ResourceType.Logs, "_logs");
        var logsPath = @"d:\jem\temp\_logs";
        var dir = logsPath + "\\app" + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }

        var filepath = Path.Combine(dir, Guid.NewGuid() + ".log");
        var fileTarget = new FileTarget("file")
        {
            FileName = filepath,
            Layout = "${date:format=yyyyMMddHHmmss} ${message}"
        };
        config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);

        var rule1 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, consoleTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule1);

        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

        InternalLogger.LogToConsole = true;

        LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
        LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }
```

This is how I instantiate the logger:

`private static NLog.Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("file");`

And this is how I use that instantiation:

```
logger.Debug("Hello world????");
```

I've tried using the ImpersonatingTargetWrapper but get the same error.  I've given 'Everyone' full rights to the root directory.  I've also tried configuration file to get started, but that didn't help either.  I've banged my head for a while against this one - anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try hard coding the path and filename directly. May be an issue with the filename

Comment: It basically is hard coded - however, rather than using a Guid.New - I just tried with a "file-log.log" and get the same error.  I've also tried using Path.GetTempPath() and I get the same error.

Comment: Which platform and NLog version? Seen this error before in xamarin as far a I remember.

Comment: I'm using NLog 4.0 running in a Unity project - so that is ultimately compiling using Mono, I believe.

Comment: Actually, NLog 4.3.3566

Comment: Could you try NLog 4.2 and file a bug? There is a problem with Mono v2, not sure if this is the same issue. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/new

Comment: Consider to set FileTarget.ConcurrentWrites=false if you don't need multiple processes writing to the same file (Also improves performance). This should stop NLog from using mutex, that is not supported by Mono ver. 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog 4.4.1 now performs runtime detection of MONO version, and avoids using named mutex if not running MONO ver. 4 or newer (Unity is running MONO ver. 2)